# How to change routing algorithm of openflows(switch) Opendaylight?

Tags: routes, dijkstra, sdn, openflow, opendaylight

I am new in Open-daylight . 
I run a topology in Mini-net then make traffics with D-IT-G . 
I want to route this traffics with Dijkstra's algorithm but i don't know how . 
How can i change default algorithm please help me step by step ?